# Is it necessary to encrypt cookie data if it just stores user preferences?

Tags: cookies, encryption

I am creating basic website which customizes the look of website based on user preference data stored in cookies. The data in cookie is stored like this:

```
country,option1,option2...and so on.
```

I read this data from the cookies directly and act on it. Is there a reason why I should encrypt it because I don't think this poses any security threat.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is a bit more nuanced than what you'd expect ...

Encryption would make the data unreadable, but that's the only thing that bare encryption does; it doesn't actually prevent the data from being modified. What you'd want instead (or in addition to encryption) is *message authentication*.
These two techniques are often used together (and if you do encryption, you surely do have to do authentication as well), but are slightly different in what they do.

If you don't store any private, sensitive information in the cookie, then you'd probably be fine without hiding (encrypting) it from the user. However, you absolutely MUST implement a message authentication mechanism.

Even if you don't think it is currently a security threat, that might be because you haven't considered all possible attack vectors or you're not actually aware of all of them. And even if it is safe *now*, that doesn't mean it will be in the future when you or your colleagues add more features or otherwise alter the application's logic.
Therefore, you must **never** trust unvalidated user input, no matter how, where, when it got into the system or how harmless it may seem at first.

*Edit note: Your question doesn't reference PHP, but I assume it as the most popular language for web application development. And I do need some language to produce an example. :)*

The easiest way to implement message authentication in PHP is by using the `hash_hmac()` function, which takes your data, a key and a cryptographic hash function name in order to produce a Hash-based Message Authentication Code (HMAC):

```
$hmac = hash_hmac('sha256', $stringCookieData, $key);
```

You can then append (or prepend) the resulting HMAC to your cookie data, which is effectively your "signature" for it:

```
$stringCookieData = $hmac.$stringCookieData;
```

And then of course, you'll need to verify that signature when you receive the cookie. In order to do that, you need to re-create the HMAC using the data that you received in the cookie and the same secret key, and finally compare the two hashes:

```
// 64 is the length of a hex-encoded SHA-256 hash
$hmacReceived = substr($_COOKIE['cookieName'], 0, 64);
$dataReceived = substr($_COOKIE['cookieName'], 64);
$hmacComputed = hash_hmac('sha256', $dataReceived, $key);

if (hash_equals($hmacComputed, $hmacReceived))
{
    // All is fine
}
else
{
    // ERROR: The received data has been modified outside of the application
}
```

There are two details here that you need to note here:

1. Just as with encryption, the key is NOT a password and it must be *random, unpredictable* (and that does NOT mean hashing the current timestamp). Always use [random_bytes()](http://php.net/random_bytes) (PHP7) or [random_compat](https://github.com/paragonie/random_compat) to generate a key. You need 32 bytes of random data for SHA-256.
2. Do NOT replace `hash_equals()` with a simple comparison operator. This function is specifically designed to prevent timing attacks, which could be used to break your key.

That's probably a lot of info to digest, but unfortunately, implementing secure applications today is very complicated. Trust me, I really did try to make it as short as possible - it is important that you understand all of the above.

Answer (score 0):

If you are fine with

- the user being able to see it
- the user being able to change it

then you do not need to encrypt it.

> I read this data from the cookies directly and act on it

Make sure you have proper validations in place. Don't trust the cookie to not be tampered with.